# What set is this LEGO pack from? Grey pieces with 10x10 octagonal plates in grey and green?

Tags: sets, set-identification

I need to know what set this LEGO pack is from as my friend gave me his packets but without the box and manual and said he lost it.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[LEGO Kingdoms - King's Castle 7946](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=7946-1).

I see the green and gray plates and other pieces the look like that

Edit to add supporting details for this answer: as of now (2022), 3 sets have at least two of each of the octagons, and only one of those has a substantial number of red pieces.

[image: 7946]